# OCR Business card Reader for Java

Tags: java, ocr

I'm searching for a tool to convert pictures of business cards to something like a vcr file in Java. 
I have already tried http://ocrsdk.com/ it works perfectly, but this is a cloud based solution.
A cloud solution does not work for me.

It could be a library but it has to be writen in Java.
It could be also something like a server product that i could install in my environment to use it as a service.

It is not a problem if i have to pay for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We evaluated this a few months ago for mobile and the only feasible (offline) solution was the [ABBYY Mobile OCR Engine](http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/). Licensing is complicated and it isn't cheap, but the scan quality is good. There are more products available for non-mobile use.